# How do I determine which member type prefix to include in a C# cref

Tags: c#

I am writing C# documentation and am using crefs quite a bit. How does one determine the right member type prefix for a cref (i.e. C, E, F, M N, P, or T) when writing the cref definition in, say an XML editor. I want to add cross references to my documentation, but I am not sure how one determines the correct member type prefix to use in a cref. Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2):

For starters, the compiler is supposed to be generating those for you. I'm not sure why you are doing this by hand.

Regardless, the list of prefixes and their uses can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsbx0t7x.aspx).

- N = Namespace
- T = Type: class, interface, struct, enum, delegate
- F = Field
- P = Property
- M = Method
- E = Event
- ! = Error String

See this article on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc837134.aspx) for examples on how to get the compiler to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to know the member type first and then find the corresponding letter. For example, if the reference is for a method, use M. If the reference is for a property, use P etc. The complete list is [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsbx0t7x.aspx)